# PHP return value after XML exploration

Tags: php, xml, function

I got a PHP array with a lot of XML users-file URL :

```
$tab_users[0]=john.xml
$tab_users[1]=chris.xml
$tab_users[n...]=phil.xml
```

For each user a <zoom> tag is filled or not, depending if user filled it up or not:

```
john.xml = <zoom>Some content here</zoom>
chris.xml = <zoom/>
phil.xml = <zoom/>
```

I'm trying to explore the users datas and display the first filled <zoom> tag, but randomized: each time you reload the page the <div id="zoom"> content is different.

```
$rand=rand(0,$n); // $n is the number of users
$datas_zoom=zoom($n,$rand);
```

My PHP function

```
function zoom($n,$rand) {   
    global $tab_users;

    $datas_user=new SimpleXMLElement($tab_users[$rand],null,true);
    $tag=$datas_user->xpath('/user');

    //if zoom found
    if($tag[0]->zoom !='') {
        $txt_zoom=$tag[0]->zoom;  
    }

    ... some other taff here

    // no "zoom" value found
    if ($txt_zoom =='') { 
       echo 'RAND='.$rand.' XML='.$tab_users[$rand].'<br />';
       $datas_zoom=zoom($r,$n,$rand); } // random zoom fct again and again till...
    }
    else {
       echo 'ZOOM='.$txt_zoom.'<br />';
       return $txt_zoom; // we got it!
    }

}

echo '<br />Return='.$datas_zoom;
```

The prob is: when by chance the first XML explored contains a "zoom" information the function returns it, but if not nothing returns... An exemple of results when the first one is by chance the good one:

```
// for RAND=0, XML=john.xml
ZOOM=Anything here

Return=Some content here // we're lucky
```

Unlucky:

```
RAND=1 XML=chris.xml

RAND=2 XML=phil.xml

// the for RAND=0 and XML=john.xml
ZOOM=Anything here 

// content founded but Return is empty

Return=
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest importing the values into a database table, generating a single local file or something like that. So that you don't have to open and parse all the XML files for each request.

Reading multiple files is a lot slower then reading a single file. And using a database even the random logic can be moved to SQL.

You're are currently using SimpleXML, but fetching a single value from an XML document is actually easier with DOM. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` only supports Xpath expression that return a node list, but `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return the scalar value directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$zoomValue = $xpath->evaluate('string(//zoom[1])');
```

`//zoom[1]` will fetch the first `zoom` element node in a node list. Casting the list into a string will return the text content of the first node or an empty string if the list was empty (no node found).

For the sake of this example assume that you generated an XML like this

```
<zooms>
  <zoom user="u1">z1</zoom>
  <zoom user="u2">z2</zoom>
</zooms>
```

In this case you can use Xpath to fetch all zoom nodes and get a random node from the list.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$zooms = $xpath->evaluate('//zoom');
$zoom = $zooms->item(mt_rand(0, $zooms->length - 1));

var_dump(
  [
    'user' => $zoom->getAttribute('user'),
    'zoom' => $zoom->textContent
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are not returning any value when there is no zoom found.

```
$datas_zoom=zoom($r,$n,$rand); // no return keyword here!
```

When you're using recursion, you usually want to "chain" return values on and on, till you find the one you need. `$datas_zoom` is not a global variable and it will not "leak out" outside of your function. Please read the [php's variable scope documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more info.

Then again, you're calling `zoom` function with three arguments (`$r,$n,$rand`) while the function can only handle two (`$n` and `$rand`). Also the `$r` is undiefined, `$n` is not used at all and you are most likely trying to use the same `$rand` value again and again, which obviously cannot work.

Also note that there are too many closing braces in your code.

I think the best approach for your problem will be to shuffle the array and then to use it like FIFO without recursion (which should be slightly faster):

```
function zoom($tab_users) {
    // shuffle an array once
    shuffle($tab_users);

    // init variable
    $txt_zoom = null;

    // repeat until zoom is found or there 
    // are no more elements in array
    do {
        $rand = array_pop($tab_users);
        $datas_user = new SimpleXMLElement($rand, null, true);
        $tag=$datas_user->xpath('/user');

        //if zoom found
        if($tag[0]->zoom !='') {
            $txt_zoom=$tag[0]->zoom;  
        }

    } while(!$txt_zoom && !empty($tab_users));

    return $txt_zoom;
}

$datas_zoom = zoom($tab_users); // your zoom is here!
```

Please read more about [php scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), [php functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) I wrote a simplified vesrion of my full code to be more clear, the $r var is in my real code (means the rep where are the xml files) and I forgot to remove it when copy-pasting my code sorry.
Got a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_shuffle()"...

Comment: My bad, the function name is just `shuffle` not `array_shuffle`. I've updated my code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for recursion. A simple loop would do.

```
$datas_user=new SimpleXMLElement($tab_users[$rand],null,true);
$tag=$datas_user->xpath('/user');

$max = $tag->length;
while(true) {
    $test_index = rand(0, $max);
    if ($tag[$test_index]->zoom != "") {
        break;
    }
}
```

Of course, you might want to add a bit more logic to handle the case where NO zooms have text set, in which case the above would be an infinite loop.